# Python - Pivot log data by dates

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a dataframe like that :

```
 Id      Date    Result
 id1     date1   result1
 id1     date2   result2
 .        .        .
 .        .        .
 id2     date11  result11
 id2     date22  result22
 .        .        .
 .        .        .
```

I want to transform this dataframe into this dataframe :

```
 Id        Vector
 id1      [date1: result1, date2: result2, ... ]
 id2      [date11: result11, date22: result22, ... ]
```

Can you help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks you,

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One note...  your desired output looks like both a list and a dict (  `[date11: result11, date22: result22, ... ]`  ).  Not sure which you really want.  I did it two ways...  outputting a dict and a list of tuples.  You should be able to modify from there to whatever you're looking for.

Full process, output as a dict...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# mimick your sample
arr = [['id1','date1','result1'],
      ['id1','date2','result2'],
      ['id2','date11','result11'],
      ['id2','date22','result22']]
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns = ['Id', 'Date', 'Result'])

# helper functions to create 'Vector' column in df2
def raw_func(dt, rslt):
    return dict(zip(dt, rslt))
func = np.vectorize(raw_func, otypes=[object])

# group by and agg into lists
df2 = df.groupby('Id').agg({'Date': list, 'Result': list})
df2
#                  Date                Result
# Id                                         
# id1    [date1, date2]    [result1, result2]
# id2  [date11, date22]  [result11, result22]

# merge Date and Result into dict
df2['Vector'] = func(df2.Date, df2.Result)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2 = df2.loc[:,['Id', 'Vector']]
df2
#   Id                                        Vector
#  id1      {'date1': 'result1', 'date2': 'result2'}
#  id2  {'date11': 'result11', 'date22': 'result22'}
```

or you could change the `dict` in `def raw_func()` to a `list`...  then your output would be a list of tuples.

```
#   Id                                    Vector
#  id1      [(date1, result1), (date2, result2)]
#  id2  [(date11, result11), (date22, result22)]
```